# Should a server call services on behalf of the user?

Tags: architecture, server

This is a general software architecture related question. This question is not related to a specifc programming language or service.

The question is: "**Should a server do things on behalf of the user without user interaction by providing the users credentials (e.g. token or certificate)?**"

The following diagram shows one option where the token/certificate will be persisted by the web API. Because doing the actual process, Service A will be called from a server. This server will ask for the credentials to create a user context and call Service A in on behalf of the user.

[image]

**Edit (adding the result of our research):**

The problem with this approach is that persisting tokens or any kind of credentials outside of the user directory is a risk. Tokens or certificates can be used to create a user context -- not only by the server, but also by others.

Instead, another option is to explicitly grant permission to the principal that is running on the server to access Service A with its own credentials. The request might include a token from Service A to let Service A know it does thing on behalf of the user. In this case, no credentials (like tokens or certificates) must be persisted. The risk of "losing" these kind of credentials does not exist.

**Edit (adding SAS Token example):**

The last option looks like this:

[image]

The Web App requests something like a SAS (Shared Access Signature) Token. This token is bound to the principal. Only the principal can use the SAS Token. Instead of persisting the users token, a SAS token is persisted.

The last option is the favorite solution, since this does not include persistance of user credentials or things that can be used to create an user context.

Edit (updating diagrams, including Service Bus)

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Does it matter? Users can't do *anything* on their own. Software always does things on behalf of the user. Unless you're speaking HTTP using a pair of little buttons and a blinking light.

Comment: @gnat, I have edited my question. I have added my concerns and the other option. Do you think this is better? This is my first post -- I have to learn ;-)

Comment: @user253751, it matters, because storing tokens or certificates outside of a user directory might be risky. So there must be other options to do the job.

Comment: The corollary to your thesis is that a server wouldn't be allowed to touch the outside world, except through clients.  It would be entirely self-contained.  I submit that, in today's connected world, such a design would limit the server's usefulness.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I have added an alternative to the first approach. This includes a SAS token. With this approach it is not needed to persist any kind of user token or certificate.

Comment: I thought that the "one server calls another server on behalf of a user" is the core premise of the microservice architecture, and is widely practiced.

Comment: @9000, is that also true when server a not directly calls server b? I have updated the diagrams to be more accurate.

Answer (score 3):

In most of my designs, the client-facing unit accepts, validates and stores the user's credentials.  It then creates one or more *other* credentials which are used only internally, but which can be associated (in log outputs) with the client and maybe with a request.  The back-end services use the credentials to identify the other back-end server(s) that presented the requests which came to them, and to ensure that they are authentic and untampered-with.  They do not know nor do they care about "clients" except to maybe know who he is.

The exchanges relative to a particular client session use internally-generated credentials that validate and encrypt the communications until that client session ends.  Then they are discarded and never used again.  So, "Eve," our erstwhile eavesdropper who has managed to add a wire to our network, never gets to accumulate a large volume of material that was encrypted with the same key.  And, even though she may have stolen the credential presented by the client, that doesn't help her intercept and decode the back-end communications.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR add the token to the Task rather than storing it separately.

Conceptually the webserver has the token in both senarios, all you are doing is extending how long it 'remembers' it for.

The whole point of these signed tokens is that you can pass them around.

The expiry date on them is supposed to prevent someone keeping them forever and using without permission. This limits the security risk from a leak to a couole of minutes.

If your process includes a significant delay this expirey will force you to go back to the user. But if not you are using the token as designed.